# Encrypt in JS and Decrypt in PHP using AES encryption algorithm in GCM and Base64 encoding

Tags: javascript, php, cryptoapi, php-openssl

I am try to Encrypt data in JS and Decrypt it in PHP using AES encryption algorithm in GCM and Base64 encoding. But during decryption I always get `false` as result without any **openssl** error. I have verify the data during transmission at frontend and backend are the same. I have also added `"ext-openssl": "*"` to my composer.json file in my laravel. What could I be doing wrong that I don't get back the result as decrypted.

Below is My encryption Method in Frontend with JS

```
async function encryptData(data, key) {
    const encoder = new TextEncoder();
    const encodedData = encoder.encode(data);
    // Ensure the key is 256 bits (32 bytes)
    if (key.length !== 32) {
        throw new Error('AES key must be 256 bits (32 bytes)');
    }
    const cryptoKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey('raw', new TextEncoder().encode(key), {
        name: 'AES-GCM'
    }, false, ['encrypt']);
    const iv = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12));
    const encrypted = await crypto.subtle.encrypt({
        name: 'AES-GCM',
        iv
    }, cryptoKey, encodedData);
    // Concatenate IV and encrypted data and convert to base64
    const combinedData = new Uint8Array(iv.length + encrypted.byteLength);
    combinedData.set(iv);
    combinedData.set(new Uint8Array(encrypted), iv.length);
    // Convert to base64 using btoa
    const base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, combinedData));
    return base64String; // Return the base64 string without URL encoding
}
```

Below is the Submission of the Encrypted data in Frontend with JS

```
async function submitData() {
    var licence = $('#licence').val();
    const encryptionKey = '12345678901234567890123456789012';

    try {
        let encryptedLicence = await encryptData(licence, encryptionKey);

        var jsonData = {
            licence: encryptedLicence
        };

        var queryParams = Object.keys(jsonData)
            .map(key => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(jsonData[key]))
            .join('&');
        var targetUrl = 'submit?' + queryParams;
        window.location.href = targetUrl;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error encrypting data:', error.message);
    }
}
```

Below is how I receive data Backend in Php

```
 public function formData(Request $request){                                           
 $key = '12345678901234567890123456789012';                     
 $data=$request->licence;                                       
 $decryptedProduct = self::decryptingMyData($data, $key);     
 dd($decryptedProduct);
 }
```

And Below is how I decrypt in Php

```
public function decryptingMyData($encryptedData, $key) {                                                          
// URL-decode the received data                                                                                 
$receivedData = urldecode($encryptedData);                                                                      
$decodedData = base64_decode($receivedData);                                                                    
$iv = substr($decodedData, 0, 12);                                                                              
$encryptedText = substr($decodedData, 12);                                                                      
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encryptedText, 'aes-256-gcm', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);                     
if ($decrypted === false) {                                                                                     
// Decryption failed                                                                                          
 $opensslError = openssl_error_string();                                                                      
 dd($decrypted ,$opensslError);                                                                                           
return decrypted;                                                                                                
}                                                                    
return $decrypted;
```

Comment: I'd advice just using GPG / PGP but that's my opinion.

Comment: GCM is authenticated encryption and uses a 16 bytes tag for authentication.  SubtleCrypto's `encrypt()` appends this tag to the ciphertext. However, PHP/OpenSSL processes ciphertext and tag separately, which is why both must be separated there: The last 16 bytes of `$encryptedText` are the tag that is to be passed as the 6th parameter in `openssl_decrypt()`, everything before that is the actual ciphertext, which is to be passed as the 1st parameter.

Comment: So How do I obtain the last 16 bytes of $encryptedText in backend so as to pass it like a tag? because currently I don't pass the tag as parameter.  additionally I have  observe the openssl_decrypt function and it looks like this . 
`function openssl_decrypt( string $data, string $cipher_algo, string $passphrase, int $options = 0, string $iv = "", string|null $tag = null, string $aad = ""
): string|false {} `

Comment: You simply have to separate ciphertext and tag: `$tag = substr($encryptedText, -16); $encryptedText = substr($encryptedText, 0, -16);` and pass both: `$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encryptedText, 'aes-256-gcm', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag);`.

Comment: @Topaco I would like to mark this as an accepting answer. Can you post it as an answer so as I can mark it. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. I put my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78012467/9014097) suggests HTTPS as an alternative for the required encryption. While HTTPS may be the better approach, the question remains as to why the posted codes are not compatible, which is addressed by the following answer.

The posted codes apply AES/GCM as algorithm. This is authenticated encryption, which uses a tag for authentication.
The WebCrypto library implicitly attaches the tag to the ciphertext, while PHP/OpenSSL processes ciphertext and tag separately. Therefore, both must be separated on the PHP/OpenSSL side and also passed separately to `openssl_decrypt()`.
This is missing in the current PHP code and can be fixed as follows:

```php
...
$tag = substr($encryptedText, -16); 
$encryptedText = substr($encryptedText, 0, -16); 
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encryptedText, 'aes-256-gcm', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag);
...
```

With this change decryption works.

---

For the sake of completeness, please note that different lengths are also possible for the tag (12 to 16 bytes, in exceptional cases also 8 and 4 bytes, see [NIST SP 800-38D](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf), sec. 5.2.1.2). The longer the tag, the more secure, which is why 16 bytes are usually applied. This is also the default value for both libraries used here.

Also keep in mind that passwords should not be used directly as keys for security reasons due to their generally lower entropy, but instead a key derivation function such as PBKDF2 in conjunction with a random salt.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you implementing this? I think this is already covered by TLS (HTTPS). Are you using HTTP instead?

Are `const encryptionKey = '12345678901234567890123456789012';` and `$key = '12345678901234567890123456789012';` actual codes instead of examples? Putting the key in plaintext makes the encryption useless. It is insecure.

Comment: some people just don't know when to stop. a smart person once said: don't do crypto yourself from scratch unless you got a decent background in cryptography and actually know what you are doing. to this day, I live up to that. I'd just use gpg here so he could have signature checking without exposing the server key. you on the other hand deserve my upvote for this, even though it could have been a comment.

Comment: @GottZ Yes, it should be a comment, but I'm new and my reputation is not enough to post a comment. However, I think in this case TLS instead of gpg should be used. gpg is also not the best choice for some other situations: https://latacora.micro.blog/2019/07/16/the-pgp-problem.html

Comment: @GottZ I just put that key there in a plain text so as to get help for clarity. But in real practice it won't look like that.

Comment: @ouuan it is just an expmale. not in real practise, I am using https

Comment: @GabrielRogath If you are using HTTPS, why do you encrypt in frontend and decrypt in backend? It's already encrypted during transportation by TLS.

Comment: @ouuan I would like to add for security for the project. Thanks for your suggestion. Appreciated.